# Efficiently iterate over one Set, and then another, in one for loop in Scala

Tags: scala, loops, scala-collections

I want to iterate over all the elements of one `Set`, and then all the elements of another `Set`, using a single loop. (I don't care about duplicates, because I happen to know the two `Set`s are disjoint.)

The reason I want to do it in a single loop is because I have some additional code to measure progress, which requires it to be in a single loop.

This doesn't work in general, because it might intermix the two `Set`s arbitrarily:

```
for(x <- firstSet ++ secondSet) {
   ...
}
```

This works, but builds 3 intermediate `Seq`s in memory, so it's far too inefficient in terms of both time and space usage:

```
for(x <- firstSet.toSeq ++ secondSet.toSeq) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for(x <- firstSet.toIterator ++ secondSet.toIterator) {
   ...
}
```

This doesn't build any intermediate data structures, so I think it's the most efficient way.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this will turn both sets into a long `List` internally when `++` is called, so it's not really efficient. Not sure why @huynhjl deleted his answer but for reference he suggested using an extra generator in the form of `for (set <- List(firstSet, secondSet); x <- set) { ... }`, which seems to be the efficient way to go.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge, I deleted my answer because I assumed that I misunderstood the question, as my solution had a nested loop. I don't know if that would still allow "to measure progress". Lacking details in the question about what is "measuring progress", I decided to delete.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge take a look at the implementation of `++` in `scala.collection.Iterator`.

Comment: Dammit, they thought of everything! I still can't think why you wouldn't just use an extra generator though.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want a traversal, and you want maximum performance, this is the best way even though it is ugly:

```
val s1 = Set(1,2,3)
val s2 = Set(4,5,6)
val block : Int => Unit = x => { println(x) }
s1.foreach(block)
s2.foreach(block)
```

Since this is pretty ugly, you can just define a class for it:

```
def traverse[T](a:Traversable[T], b:Traversable[T]) : Traversable[T] = 
  new Traversable[T] { 
    def foreach[U](f:T=>U) { a.foreach(f); b.foreach(f) } 
  }
```

And then use it like this:

```
for(x<-traverse(s1, s2)) println(x)
```

However, unless this is extremely performance-critical, the solution posted by Robin Green is better. The overhead is creation of two iterators and concatenation of them. If you have deeper nested data structures, concatenating iterators can be quite expensive though. For example a tree iterator that is defined by concatenating the iterators of the subtrees will be painfully slow, whereas a tree traversable where you just call foreach on each subtree will be close to optimal.